# motion leap - swipe detection not working

Tags: java, swipe, leap-motion

```
 @Override
    public void onFrame(Controller arg0) {
        Frame frame = arg0.frame();
        for (int i = 0; i < frame.gestures().count(); i++) {
            Gesture gesture = frame.gesture(i);
            if (gesture.type() != Type.TYPE_INVALID)
                System.out.println(gesture.type().toString());
        }
    }
```

I get no message in console.
If i remove that if, i will get a lot of invalid swipes.
I've tried doing a lot of types of swipes but nothing seems to work.
Example of swipe that i tried:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dj1q8Bjn-uk[image]

Comment: A couple questions: Does the Sample program in the SDK print out gesture info for you? Are you enabling gestures earlier in your program? Do you see swipe gestures drawn in the Visualizer (press "O" to turn on gesture drawing)?

Comment: Yes, i see in the visualier, and i enable the swipe gesture type, along with all the other gestures, check this http://pastebin.com/ceArn4fY

Comment: I should have seen the error sooner; it is a common mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `frame.gesture(id)` searches the frame's gesture list for a gesture object with the specified id, i.e. so that you can track a particular gesture across frames. The function returns an invalid frame if it doesn't find one. Change your code to use `frame.gestures()`, which gives you the gesture list:

```
@Override
public void onFrame(Controller arg0) {
    Frame frame = arg0.frame();
    for (int i = 0; i < frame.gestures().count(); i++) {
        Gesture gesture = frame.gestures().get(i);
        if (gesture.type() != Type.TYPE_INVALID)
            System.out.println(gesture.type().toString());
    }
}
```

You shouldn't ever get invalid gestures in the list supplied by the gestures() function, so you don't really need that check in this case.

Comment: You should make the loop more compact by using the foreach loop: for (Gesture g : gestures) {...}